# DockBarX autostart breaks shutdown menus

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, autostart, dockbarx

Since I installed DockBarX in Ubuntu 14.04, I am unable to access the shutdown menus (shutdown, log-out, lock, et cetera) from the top-right gear-like menu. I can click on it, but nothing happens.

If I remove DockBarX from autostart, and I start it manually, it works again as it should, but it's a bit annoying.

Someone else have this problem? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had also the same issue recently with DockBarX. To fix it, I just added a delay for the DockBarX application to start. Modify the startup command to following:

```
sh -c "sleep 8 && dockx"
```

The number 8 is the delay and it can vary with machines. So try a lower value like 5 first and increase it till the issue is resolved.

Same issue is also having with Cairo dock. They can use the following startup command:

```
sh -c "sleep 8 && cairo-dock -o"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this delay solution.

I confirm it works on Dell Inspiron E1405, Ubuntu 14.04, with the lowest possible value of 3, which I assume is three seconds. If I go down to 2 seconds, it hijacks the shutdown options.

Once again, thanks a bunch!